# Is there any way to create a root level column-object in Python dataframe like struct type in Scala?

Tags: python, scala, dataframe

I need to write some data to dataset, and I need to have one column as root and three more columns inside that column. How I can do that in Python? I have working code for Scala.

```
var myDf  = myDf.withColumn(rootColumn, struct(myDf("column1"), myDf("column2"), myDf("column3")))
```

I have tried with pd.MultiIndex.from_product, I get rootColumn at the top, but that is not working with this situation. I need exact result like in Spark code above.
Schema have three columns, one is root, and inside that root column I have multiple columns.I need to make changes so I can write dataframe to the dataset based on that schema.